# How to pass json parameters for Jenkins using CURL?

Tags: json, linux, curl, jenkins-groovy, groovydsl

I'm trying to build a job by passing JSON parameter for Jenkins through Linux CLI. But I'm not able to pass the parameters in JSON. I have used -g to turn off globbing. Still the issue persists. Any help would be appreciated.

```
curl -X POST -u username:password -g JENKINS_URL/job/Bulk_Job/buildWithParameters?serviceBranchJson="{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}"
```

Error message

```
Processing provided DSL script
{key1:value1,key2:value2}
groovy.json.JsonException: expecting '}' or ',' but got current char 'k' with an int value of 107

The current character read is 'k' with an int value of 107
expecting '}' or ',' but got current char 'k' with an int value of 107
line number 1
index number 1
{key1:value1,key2:value2}
```

Code snippet

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

def serviceBranchJson = serviceBranchJson

println(serviceBranchJson)

Map servicesMap = new JsonSlurper().parseText(serviceBranchJson)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your JSON is missing quotes around the keys and values. From your error message, the json is `{key1:value1,key2:value2}` and it should be: `{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}` to work properly.

Try to escape the quotes in your curl command, for example:

```
curl -u user:token "JENKINS_URL/job/Bulk_Job/buildWithParameters?serviceBranchJson={\"key1\":\"value1\",\"key2\":\"value2\"}"
```

Then it should work correctly with your pipeline code (I added `println servicesMap` to the end of the code):

```
Started by remote host ...
[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
[Pipeline] echo
{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}
[Pipeline] echo
{key1=value1, key2=value2}
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: SUCCESS
```